# Detect multiple span ids has class=“active” and if button is pressed

Tags: jquery

I have span set and some of them have class=“active”. I need all the span ids which have active class.And also there can be other tags which have active class as well.

```
<div id="myDiv">
<span id="sp1" class="active"></span>
<span id="sp2"></span>
<span id="sp3" class="active"></span>
<span id="sp4"></span>
<span id="sp5"></span>

</div>
```

i tried following script but it's not working.

```
var IDs = [];
        $('#myDiv').find('span').hasClass('active').each(function(){ 
                        IDs.push(this.id); 

        });
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 5):

`.hasClass()` returns boolean which is why the code you have isn't working. Instead, you can do something like this:

```
var IDs = $('#myDiv').find('span.active').map(function() { return this.id; }).get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this!

```js
var IDs = [];
$('#myDiv').find('span.active').each(function() {
  IDs.push($(this).attr('id'));  
});
console.log(IDs);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv">
  <span id="sp1" class="active"></span>
  <span id="sp2"></span>
  <span id="sp3" class="active"></span>
  <span id="sp4"></span>
  <span id="sp5"></span>
</div>
```